# Browserify - Load file from the server into the client using fs

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I have some experience with node but I am new to Browserify and I wonder if its possible to load files stored on the server into the client browser using fs with Browserify.

Is this something feasible? Is there some limitations?

Comment: There is no stupid question... only stupid answer but Quentin's answer is a good one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `fs` is native to Node. It isn't available in a browser. The usual solution is to expose the file over HTTP and then read it with the XMLHttpRequest object.